# Can I Use a foreach here for Multiple Uploads?

Tags: php, html, image, file-upload, foreach

I have an image upload button on a form with text inputs but the script that is desigened to check, resize and upload the files is only designed for one upload.

Is there a way I can feed each file to this script using a foreach() with the following code?

```
if (($_FILES['file']['type'] != 'image/jpeg') && ($_FILES['file']['type'] != 'image/jpg') && ($_FILES['file']['type'] != 'image/pjpeg')) {
            echo "<script>alert('Images Must be in jpg format and under 2 Mb');\n";
            echo sprintf("window.location='add.php'");
            echo "</script>";
            include('no-ad-footer.php');
                } else {
                chdir('admin/photos'); 
                require_once('upload.php');
                chdir('../../');

        if ($up->ValidateUpload()) { 
                $node = new sqlNode();
                $node->table = "photos";
                $node->push("int","TypeID",$_POST['TypeID']);
                $node->push("int","ListingID",$ListingID);          
                $node->push("text","Location",$new_name);           
                $node->push("int","POrder",$_POST['POrder']);
                $node->push("defined","DateofUpload","NOW()");

                if(($result = $mysql->insert($node)) === false)
                    die('Unable to push photo details into table photos line 38');          
            } else {
                echo "<font color='red'>Unable to upload image</font>";
                }
        }
```

Comment: I need some help, What if I have 4 image upload buttons? Do I name them all "file"?

Comment: name them file1,file2... and then foreach over $_FILES

Comment: I ask this because the script is based off of $_FILES['file']['type'] with "file" being the name that the script calls the file with. I don't really know what all I would have to change  in the script if $_FILES['file']['type'] was changed to $_FILES['image1']['type'] or $_FILES['image2']['type']... etc

Comment: @YourCommonSense Could you show me an example??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't try it but this should work:

```
$ftypelist = array('image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/pjpeg');

foreach($_FILES as $file){
    if(in_array($file[type], $ftypelist){
        echo "<script>alert('Images Must be in jpg format and under 2 Mb');\n";
        echo sprintf("window.location='add.php'");
        echo "</script>";
        include('no-ad-footer.php');
    } else {
        chdir('admin/photos'); 
        require_once('upload.php');
        chdir('../../');

        if ($up->ValidateUpload()) { 
            $node = new sqlNode();
            $node->table = "photos";
            $node->push("int","TypeID",$_POST['TypeID']);
            $node->push("int","ListingID",$ListingID);          
            $node->push("text","Location",$new_name);           
            $node->push("int","POrder",$_POST['POrder']);
            $node->push("defined","DateofUpload","NOW()");

            if(($result = $mysql->insert($node)) === false)
                die('Unable to push photo details into table photos line 38');          
        } else {
            echo "<font color='red'>Unable to upload image</font>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @panosrob, I really appreciate you taking the time to share this with me. I'll be looking into how I can implement it and I thank you once again!!